# Add syntax highlighting to certain file extensions for VIM or GVIM by default

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

In my Linux machine files with the `.sv` extension opens up by default with the verilog syntax highlighting scheme, however extension with `.v`or `.vs` don't. 
I have to manually in gvim do a `:set syntax=verilog` every time I open one of these files.

How do I make those file extensions `.v` or `.vs` open up in a verilog syntax highlighting by default ?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add an auto-command to your *.vimrc* to do that for you:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.v,*.vs set syntax=verilog
```

Comment: The "correct" place to put these is in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`; see `:help new-filetype`. (`~/.vimrc` mostly works, too.)

Comment: There are the two lines of though...for me personally it makes more sense to keep these simple configuration settings in _.vimrc_.

Comment: @IngoKarkat In my case, setting the filetype via `filetype.vim` didn't work because I needed to override a filetype that was already detected correctly but didn't provide syntax highlighting.

Comment: `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.v,*.sv,*.vs set syntax=verilog` (same, but including *.sv) just in case your setup doesn't recognize .sv already

Comment: @IngoKarkat From the :help new-filetype => "In any way, it's better not to modify the $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim
file.  It will be overwritten when installing a new version of Vim."
They then suggest to put a file with the autocommand in a folder called ftdetect. Perhaps they updated the help since you commented.

Comment: @SteakOverflow: The help mentions _four ways_. Your is referred to as option A, while mine is option C. Both are fine; one is fine-granular, the other keeps everything in one place. I actually use both approaches in parallel :-)